# Generate higher dimensional box vectors

Tags: list-manipulation

I'd like to generate integer vectors in $\{-M,-M+1,\dots,M\}^n$, where $M$ and $n$ are parameters. For a fixed $n$, say $n=3$ for instance, I only know I can use

```
Flatten[Table[{i, j, k}, {i, -M, M}, {j, -M, M}, {k, -M, M}]]
```

to get the list. But for larger $n$, I would have to add more coordinate ranges manually. Is there an automatic way to do this?

I have a similar question on `Sum` and `NSum`; for instance, I want to compute $\sum_x e^{-\|x\|^2}$ for $x$ over $\{-M,\dots,M\}^n$. For $n=3$ I could write

```
NSum[E^(-(i^2 + j^2 + z^2)), {i, -M, M}, {j, -M, M}, {k, -M, M}]
```

Is there a more automatic way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t = Tuples[Range[-m,m], n]` will give you the list of `n`-tuples.
Then `s = Total[Exp[-#.#]& /@ t]` is one way to get the sum.

EDIT: There are several faster ways to get the sum. If all you want `t` for is to get `s` then it's faster to go directly to `s = Total@Exp[-Total[Tuples[Range[-m,m]^2, n], {2}]]`, omitting `t`. If you want just a number, as opposed to its symbolic representation in terms of powers of `E`, use `N@Range` instead of `Range`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to go about this kind of thing:

```
m=3;
Outer[List, #, #, #] & @ Range[-m, m]
```

This gives the same thing as the `Table` command, which you can `Flatten` if desired.
To add new dimensions, just increase the number of #'s, for instance:

```
Outer[List, #, #, #, #, #] & @ Range[-m, m]
```

As ybeltukov suggests, this can be made more general using `Sequence`

```
Outer[List, Sequence @@ ConstantArray[Range[-m, m], n]]
```

where now `n` is the number of required dimensions. Or one could do

```
Outer[List, Sequence @@ ConstantArray[#, 3]] & @ Range[-m,m]
```

which uses `ConstantArray` to generate all the #'s and `Sequence` to splice them into the function.

Comment: I think `Outer[List, Sequence @@ ConstantArray[Range[-m, m], n]]` is better.